# Enabling NAT forwarding using a second WAN interface and a second gateway on ubuntu

Tags: iptables, nat, gateway

I have 3 interfaces:

```
eth0 192.168.0.50/24
eth1 10.0.0.200/24
eth2 225.228.123.211
```

The default gateway is `192.168.0.1` which I want to keep as it is in the changes I want to make.

I want to masquerade `eth1 10.0.0.200/24` and enable NAT forwarding to `eth2`. So I have done this:

```
ip route add 225.228.123.208/29 dev eth2 src 225.228.123.211 table t1
ip route add default via 225.228.123.209 dev eth2 table t1

ip rule add from 225.228.123.211 table t1
ip rule add to 225.228.123.211 table t1
```

Now I can receive ping replies from any internet host if I did:

```
ping -I eth2 8.8.8.8
```

To enable NAT forwarding I did this:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth2 -i eth1 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it isn't working. To test I used a client pc and put it on `10.0.0.0/24` network and gateway was set as `10.0.0.200`.

I want to have `192.168.0.1` as default gateway. And the traffic that comes in via `eth1 10.0.0.200/24` should be forwarded to `eth2 225.228.123.211`.

I have enabled forwarding on ubuntu also.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding "it's not working"? In what way it didn't work?

Comment: More question: are you sure the address for eth2 starts with 225? AFAIK 224-239 are multicast addresses.

Comment: @pepoluan I have not given my acutal public ip, I intentionally randomized it. When I used a client machine to access internet it didn't work.

Comment: okay, fair enough. was typing a solution for you last night when I realized the address is strange. will type the solution again later today. (tip: next time, use 11.22.33.44 ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the tip, pepoluan. I will suerly use it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to:

- Route everyone from eth1 10.0.0.0/24 through eth2
- Yet maintain the Linux box's routing via eth0

If that's the case, there are several mistakes with your iptables & iproute2 settings. Here's my suggestion:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

For the routing, you'll need two custom tables. I'll use numbers instead of names because I don't know what's in your `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. Now, one important note: Modifying the RPDB and default routes my way *will* cause temporary network disturbance. So I'd suggest *not* typing these on the CLI, instead put it in a script, so everything happens atomically (unless you're typing the commands on the Linux box's physical console).

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1     dev eth0 table 100
ip route add default via 225.228.123.209 dev eth2 table 102
ip route del default table main

ip rule add order 10 from all lookup main
ip rule add order 20 iif lo   lookup 100
ip rule add order 30 iif eth1 lookup 102
```

We move the `lookup main` as the first rule to ensure proper routing to subnets directly attached to the Linux box. But we delete the default route in that table, because we want to specify different default routes depending on where the packet enters the Linux box.

Now, here's an important question: **Is the subnet 10.0.0.0/24 represents *all* networks attached -- directly or indirectly -- to eth1?**

**If YES,** then the configuration is finished.

**If NO,** i.e., there are other subnets indirectly attached to eth1 (let's say, 10.0.1.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24, etc.) which you can access through another router (let's say, 10.0.0.77/24) then you have to add more routes to the `main` table:

```
ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.77 dev eth1 table main
ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.0.77 dev eth1 table main
... and so on ...
```

***Note:** `table main` is not necessary, but a good habit*

Comment: I have only one subnet on eth1. I put both firwall rules and ip route rules in two different files. When I executed those scripts, the firewall script got executed but ip route script gave an error. The only thing I modfied in the ip route script was instead of using 100 and 102 as table names I used `t1` and `t2`. In the rt_tables file I had put `200 t1` and `210 t2` in two different lines

Comment: @nixnotwin can you try entering the `ip` statements one-by-one and tell me which one results in an error? and what's the error message?

Comment: @pepoluan, it worked. I carefully removed all the earlier entered rules, and executed your script, with echo function inserted between each lines to discover the failing line, but it got executed without any errors. The forwarding and masquerading works fine too. One thing remains to be done is figuring out where to place all those rules so that they get applied at boot-up. One thing more: I can't do `ping -I eth2 8.8.8.8` on the server-router. It is not necessary actually. Just wanted to let you know. Well, massive thanks.

Comment: @nixnotwin glad to hear that it works :) .. well, the router can't send packets out eth2 because of the 'iif lo' ip rule. you can test it by entering `ip rule order 15 iif lo lookup <table that's used by 'iif eth1'>`, then erasing the new rule `ip rule del order 15` when you're done

Comment: @nixnotwin oh, and for the rules to start automatically, there are lots of ways. but the easiest is: create a script (say, `/etc/${HOSTNAME}-autoexec.sh`. careful, do not clobber an existing script) and call it from `/etc/rc.local` (right before `exit 0`). just remember that you must use the full path to `ip` and `iptables` (use the `which` command to find out).

Comment: @pepoluan Thanks. I added an upstart job for the route scripts ( made it run when filesystem and interface=eth2 comes up) and used the following guide for iptables script https://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configuring_IPtables_on_ubuntu_server

Comment: @pepoluan this site http://www.andrewault.net/2010/05/17/securing-an-ubuntu-server/ says that having source forwarding of incoming packets is security risk. Does it have anything to do with enabimg packet forwarding to make ubuntu a router?

Comment: @nixnotwin "source routing" is an option of IPv4 packets in which source hosts can explicitly ask through where they should be routed (i.e., not necessarily according to the routing table in the router). rarely used nowadays, but may indeed cause security issues. you really should follow the site's suggestions to disable source routing. disabling source routing has no effect to Ubuntu iproute2 forwarding (aside from making it more secure)

Comment: @nixnotwin forgot to add: disable source routing, but *do not* disable forwarding. the site that you linked to gave another site ( http://www.cromwell-intl.com/security/security-stack-hardening.html ) which gives instructions applicable mostly to hosts, not routers.

Comment: Thanks pepoluan, now everything works fine. I have about 200 users who mostly are heavy users, who download large files. So I need to figure out how to do QOS. I even asked a question on this site about qos.

Comment: @nixnotwin in that case, I can't help you yet. I'm still trying to figure out the vagaries of `tc` myself. Complex just doesn't begin to describe it xP. Hope someone can help you :)

Comment: Here is a nice QOS howto which appears similar to tomato firmware QOS http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1276396